# Need to get profile information after successful login to facebook

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, facebook-authentication

Totally new to this API I am working on a web site that uses Facebook API to allow them to log in.  The code is old and now does not work so I am trying to upgrade to use new SDK.  I am correctly getting them to login using this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiID"] %>', // App ID
        channelUrl: 'http://<%= Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] %>/channel.html', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
</script>
```

and this link:

```
<strong><a href="#" class="sIcoFB" onclick="FB.login(function(response) { if (response.authResponse) { scope: 'publish_stream,email'; parent.location = '<%=Server.UrlDecode(redirectPath)%>'; } else { alert('Please sign in to access the site'); } });">Login using Facebook</a></strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

This seems to work as then you can open facebook.com and you are logged in correctly.  However I cannot seem to find how to check this in C#.  I have this so far:

```
//Facebook Authenticated, created session and API object
_connectSession = new FacebookClient();

//example of getting access code
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("client_id", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiID"]);
parameters.Add("redirect_uri", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
parameters.Add("client_secret", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"]);
parameters.Add("scope", "publish_stream,email");

IDictionary<string, object> result = (IDictionary<string, object>)_connectSession.Get("/oauth/access_token", parameters);

string accessToken = (string)result["access_token"];
```

However I get this error:

(OAuthException - #1) Missing authorization code

If anyone can point me in the direction of how in C# I can get the profile information as we already have the ID in our database I just need to log them in as one of our users.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `code` parameter needed to fetch the access_token - the exception appears to be correct. Check the server side-flow in the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation

You likely just need to include the `code` parameter you received when the user was redirected back to your app from the auth dialog - the other parameters in your call to fetch the access token look correct

Comment: Sorry to sound lost but I saw the code parameter and have read the docs but what is that code referring to?

Comment: Follow the steps of the server side oauth flow carefully- the user goes to the auth dialog, they get set back to your app with a `code` parameter in the query string - you exchange that `code` for an access token, and verify that you're the same app that the user saw the auth dialog for by providing the `client_id` and `client_secret` - in your case you're missing the `code` in that call

Answer (score 0):

I have this test page below, which is code straight from Facebook developers.  It is suppose to prompt you to login and then put your picture and name in the elements.  While it logs you in correctly it does not update.

** updated code, this now works ***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testfb.aspx.cs" Inherits="testfb" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" charset="utf-8">    </script>        
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
</head>
<body>                    
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
          FB.init({
              appId: '111081862265698', // App ID
              channelUrl: '//<%= Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] %>/channel.html', //     Channel File
              status: true, // check login status
              cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
          });
          FB.login(function (response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                  alert('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                  FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                      alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                      var image = document.getElementById('image');
                      image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture';
                      var name = document.getElementById('name');
                      name.innerHTML = response.name
                  });
              } else {
                  alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
              }
          });         
      };
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function (d) {
          var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
          js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      } (document));
  </script>

  <div align="center">
    <img id="image"/>
    <div id="name"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fb-login-button" scope="email">
    Login with Facebook
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```